# Application of Schwarz's lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

Adapt the proof of Schwarz's lemma to prove the following. Let $f$ be analytic in the unit disk $U=\{z:|z|<1\}$ having zeros at $z=\frac{1}{2}$ and $z=-\frac{1}{2}$, and such that $|f(z)|<1$ for all $z \in U$. Prove that $|f(i/2)|\le 8/17$.

I just tried but messed up. Can anyone give me some ideas to stab this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Schwarz lemma, you get an upper bound for $\left\lvert g\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)\right\rvert$ for all holomorphic $g \colon U \to U$ with $g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = 0$. Now consider

$$T(z) = \frac{z+\frac{1}{2}}{1+\frac{z}{2}}$$

and

$$g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{T(z)}.$$

Comment: This is a really smart idea! I figured out all the gaps. First, we can prove f is analytic and $|g(z)|\le 1$ on the boundary, then by maximum modulo principle, $g$ defined in the end satisfies the class you said. Also the upper bound is $\sqrt{8/17}$, also $|T(i/2)|=\sqrt{8/17}$. So the question is solved. Thanks you very much.

Comment: I'm interested in this problem too but I didn't figure out this way. Could you share some motivations on this question?